# Switched to Elementary OS last night, now my internet is insanely slow

Tags: internet, epiphany

So on pop!_OS I was pulling 275 Mbs yesterday. I switched to elementary and now can’t load the webpage that I did my initial speed test on yesterday because my browser is that bad. I’ll probably have to go back to pop! because this is going to be impossible to get through school with, but are there any simple fixes for this?

My rig: 2019 Razer blade stealth 13
Processor: intel core i7-8565u 1.8ghz
Graphics: NVIDIA MX150

Edit- did a speed test on google, 256 mbs, went to leave google, 34 seconds to load Reddit.
Also don’t know how much it matters but before switching OS’s I downloaded the most recent NVIDIA Graphics driver

Answer (score 0):

Based on your good results with Google but slow page loading times for other sites, it sounds like you might have a bad DNS resolver configuration. I would first examine your resolver settings with

```
$ resolvectl status
```

and see if your network interface(s) might perhaps be pointing to an invalid or very slow DNS server. Note that DNS servers are searched in sequential order. As an experiment, you could try using Google’s or Cloudflare’s public DNS servers and see if that improves your page load times:

```
$ sudo resolvectl dns INTERFACE 1.1.1.1
```

or

```
$ sudo resolvectl dns INTERFACE 8.8.8.8
```

where `INTERFACE` is the short name of your desired network interface (e.g., `wlan0` or `eth0`).